# Running a SQL query for each month - PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, while-loop

Im looking for some help to run this query for each month.

```
$params = array(&$_POST['query']);

$SQL1 = "SELECT SUM(Income) AS OrderTotal 
FROM SalesDB
WHERE
SalesDB.[Posting Date] <= '2013-01-01' AND
SalesDB.[Posting Date] >= '2013-01-31'";

$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$getProducts1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL1, $params, $options);
if ($getProducts1 === false)
die( var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()) ); 

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
$row['OrderTotal'];
}
```

In this way, i get the Total income of January. Is there any way to do a loop, so it runs a query for each month in this year?

So i don't have to do it this stupid way:

```
$params = array(&$_POST['query']);

    $SQL1 = "SELECT SUM(Income) AS OrderTotal 
    FROM SalesDB
    WHERE
    SalesDB.[Posting Date] <= '2013-01-01' AND
    SalesDB.[Posting Date] >= '2013-01-31'";

    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $getProducts1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL1, $params, $options);
    if ($getProducts1 === false)
    die( var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()) ); 

$SQL2 = "SELECT SUM(Income) AS OrderTotal 
    FROM SalesDB
    WHERE
    SalesDB.[Posting Date] <= '2013-02-01' AND
    SalesDB.[Posting Date] >= '2013-02-28'";

    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $getProducts2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL2, $params, $options);
    if ($getProducts2 === false)
    die( var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()) ); 

    while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) AND $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
    echo $row1['OrderTotal'];
echo $row2['OrderTotal'];

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY`. This query will get all income totals for 2013, in date order:

```
$params = array(&$_POST['query']);

$SQL1 = "SELECT SUM(Income) AS OrderTotal
FROM SalesDB
WHERE
YEAR(SalesDB.[Posting Date]) = '2013'
GROUP BY MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date])
ORDER BY MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date])";

$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL1, $params, $options);
if ($getProducts === false)
die( var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()) );

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['OrderTotal'];
}
```

To show `0` instead of `NULL` for dates without any data, you can `COALESCE` the result:

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT COALESCE(0,SUM(Income)) AS OrderTotal
         FROM SalesDB
         WHERE YEAR(SalesDB.[Posting Date]) = '2013'
         GROUP BY MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date])
         ORDER BY MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date])";
```

Comment: Is it possible to run the query 12 times, even though the data for month 4-12 is empty?

So it posts 0 instead of null

I'm using it for comparison with some forecast

Comment: @nielskildsgaard If I've understood you correctly, you want to get a 0 in the result for future dates rather than NULL values? I've updated the answer to use `COALESCE`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Right now, it just replaces the data i have with 0 :)
So i tried with COALESCE(SUM(Income),0)

Comment: But the thing is, it doesnt post "NULL", it just stops posting after month 1-3 has been queried.

Comment: I'll be honest and say I'm not 100% sure of the solution but try here for a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129611/return-zero-value-when-no-row-data-exists

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to get SUM(income) by month and year?

And your field is: SalesDB.[Posting Date]  ?

Here's how I would do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(Income) AS OrderTotal, YEAR(alesDB.[Posting Date]) AS year, MONTH(alesDB.[Posting Date]) AS month
FROM SalesDB
GROUP BY YEAR(alesDB.[Posting Date]), MONTH(alesDB.[Posting Date])";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the records by months but you need to use `MONTH()` in order to get the month value of the dates.

```
SELECT  MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date]) MonthNo,
        DATENAME(month, SalesDB.[Posting Date]) MonthName,
        SUM(Income) OrderTotal
FROM    SalesDB
WHERE   SalesDB.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP   BY  MONTH(SalesDB.[Posting Date]), 
            DATENAME(month, SalesDB.[Posting Date])
ORDER   BY MonthNo ASC
```

Comment: That won't include any of December's data

Comment: @BrendanBullen oops. *copy-paste* thing. fixed.